# Resizing window with flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page where I am using a CSS Flexbox with some elements inside it. As of now, if I resize the window to make it smaller, the elements shrink proportionately and are still all displayed on the page.

I'd like it to be the case that when I make the window smaller, some of the elements in the Flexbox disappear, and I have to scroll back and forth to see them.

What is the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: I've made the flexbox fixed, but that doesn't allow me to scross back and forth.

Comment: Try `min-width` and `min-height` properties

Answer (score 1):

Try the `min-height` and `min-width`properties.

Here is an [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz8tLv58/). Try resizing the window to see the effect.